# Can I create sperate queries for different views?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm learning sqlalchemy and not sure if I grasp it fully yet(I'm more used to writing queries by hand but I like the idea of abstracting the queries and getting objects).  I'm going through the tutorial and trying to apply it to my code and ran into this part when defining a model:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<User('%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
```

Its useful because I can just search for a username and get only the info about the user that I want but is there a way to either have multiple of these type of views that I can call? or am I using it wrong and should be writing a specific query for getting different data for different views?

Some context to why I'm asking my site has different templates, and most pages will just need the usersname, first/last name but some pages will require things like twitter or Facebook urls(also fields in the model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `__repr__` is not a view, so if you have a simple model `User` with defined columns, and you query for a `User`, all the columns will get loaded from the database, and not only those used in `__repr__`.

Lets take model `Book` (from the example refered to later) as a basis:

```
class Book(Base):
    book_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    summary = Column(String(2000))
    excerpt = Column(Text)
    photo = Column(Binary)
```

The first option to skip loading some columns is to use [Deferred Column Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#deferred-column-loading):

```
class Book(Base):
    # ...
    excerpt = deferred(Column(Text))
    photo = deferred(Column(Binary))
```

In this case when you execute query `session.query(Book).get(1)`, the `photo` and `excerpt` columns will not be loaded until accessed from the code, at which point another query against the database will be executed to load the missing data.
But if you know before you query for the `Book` that you need the column `photo` immediately, you can still override the deferred behavior with undefer option: `query = session.query(Book).options(undefer('photo')).get(1)`.

Basically, the suggestion here is to *defer* all the columns (in your case: except username, password etc) and in each use case (view) override with [`undefer`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.undefer) those you know you need for that particular view. Please also see the `group` parameter of `deferred`, so that you can group the attributes by use case (view).

Another way would be to query only some columns, but in this case you are getting the `tuple` instance instead of the model instance (in your case `User`), so it is potentially OK for form filling, but not so good for model validation: `session.query(Book.id, Book.title).all()`